# clad as an active verb?

Tags: verbs, past-participles, active-voice

I've been spending some time on a home repair forum and I keep coming across the word *clad* used in the imperative or present tense active form.

E.g.

- Clad your home in brick.
- He clads his home in brick.

This feels very wrong to me, but I don't know why. Previously, I've only ever seen the verb used passively or as an adjective or noun.

E.g.

- The home was clad in brick.
- The home was brick-clad.
- Brick cladding covered the home.

And now I've typed *clad* so many times all the forms sound strange to me!  What are the rules for this word?

Comment: [From etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=clad): *clad* an obsolete past tense for *clothe*.  So etymologically it should be *clothe your house in brick*, which doesn't sound any better.

Comment: I doubt that one person in a hundred who uses *clad* knows that it's an archaic past/past participle of the verb *clothe*; and that one person is probably going to resist using *clothe* in the sense "provide with cladding". So it's perfectly natural that anybody finding a need for an active verb meaning "provide with cladding" should recategorize *clad* to meet that need. ... or, more simply, what Peter Shor says.

Comment: @PeterShor: that's exactly my problem. I feel that clad is wrong, but I can't come up with any versions I like better. If I had to use an active verb in the present tense, I'd probably use *cover*. But that's a different verb altogether!

Comment: The verb "clad" (meaning to encase a structure), has a full paradigm, so your examples are fine,  It is widely used in the construction industry.

Comment: @PeterShor Apparently, it wasn't only a past tense. Edmund Spencer used it as a present tense verb "to clad". I have found several instances. "to clad his corpse with meete habiliments", "Him in deares skin to clad". I got several hits from Scottsmen throughout the centuries. Mostly poetic, but then brickmasons didn't contribute much of the corpus. It has been a standard verb in industrial processes for a long time.

Comment: *go clad* also garners a few hits. "I will go clad my bodie in gaie ornaments".

Comment: Giving an obsolete past tense *(clad)* a whole new paradigm *(to clad)* is a neat example of *back formation*, a legitimate device for extending English.

Comment: Anecdotal evidence: Use of clad as an active verb strikes me as totally natural, though I can't say off the top of my head when or where I've heard/seen it used that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [contemporary vernacular usage](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/clad?s=t) generally meaning "clothed", though it can also mean "covered" which would be closer to the usage you are describing.

There is also a [jargon term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cladding_(construction)) in construction meaning "to cover one material with another". Being an industry term, and with a vastly more common usage that is similarly specific, this usage seems correct but sounds odd to me as well.